# Proof using pidgeon-hole principle

Tags: combinatorics

If we have the set $Y=\{1,2,3...2014\}$ and $X$ is some subset of $Y$, I'm to prove that if $|X|\geq64$ then there exists pairs $\{x,y\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ for some $x,y,a,b \in X$ for which $|x-y| = |a-b|$. I'm fairly sure this can be shown using pidgeon-hole principles, but I'm having real trouble braining it out. Any ideas how I can proceed?

Comment: Hint: How many pairs $\{x,y\}$ (with $x$ and $y$ distinct) does $X$ have at least?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
A=\{|x-y|:x\neq y\in Y\}=\{1,\ldots,2013\}
$$
which contains $2013$ numbers. With $|X|\geq 64$, there are at least $\frac{1}{2}64\times 63=2016$ distinct (non-ordered) pairs that can be picked from $X$. Because $2016>2013$, there must exist at least 2 pairs that share the same absolute difference between the pair members.